# Validating properties of a class where you don't have control of the data or the class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to learn a smart, design pattern-ish way of validating the properties of a library class that holds the data of an e-commerce order returned from a web-service (eBay SDK).

There are other questions on this, but I haven't been able to apply them to my situation because:

- The class I want to validate is from an SDK, it does not have properties marked virtual, deriving from it means I have to hide the base properties with new and call base in the new properties to access them.
- If I derive from the base class and use the new modifier with base.propertyName, to effectively duplicate the class properties and also be able to add the validation attributes above them, I cannot cast the object I'm trying to validate to this derived class with attributes to be able to call .Validate() as you cannot 'cast up' from a base-type to a derived type.

Is there any approach to contract-style class properties validation, whereby you have no class-definition control of the class you're validating? Instead of creating a validator class that has 20 if-statements doing null-checking and logic on each property?

I only need this for a specific object and I know the properties and what values are valid, I just don't feel passing the order to a class with a bunch of if-statements is good in terms of maintainability and code-quality.

Here is the code I was thinking of for the derived type I could invoke .Validate() on, I stopped writing this as I don't know how to take baseclass, transform it into this class:

```
    public class ValidatableOrderType : eBay.Service.Core.Soap.OrderType
    {
        public ValidatableOrderType(eBay.Service.Core.Soap.OrderType baseType)
        {

        }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "OrderID cannot be null.")]
        new public string OrderID
        {
            get { return base.OrderID; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best choice its to use fluentvalidator.

https://fluentvalidation.net/

Its a brilliant software for validation even more powerful than metadata attributes.

I hope this helps you

Comment: That looks like a good library with a really big userbase, perhaps I will go with this. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Please check it as a valid answer with the check

Comment: The check isn't for a valid answer, it's for the answer that solves your problem best. I have ticked your answer as I've found a few SOLID ways of implementing a validation methodology but it seems a lot smarter to use that library.